# How to Configure Distributed Ehcache

Tags: caching, jdbc, ehcache, distributed-caching

I want to configure Ehcache instances on different VMs and run a servlet on the host, using those caches as data storage. The cache servers have to form a cluster, for distributed caching.

I searched anywhere (google, stackoverflow, Ehcache documentation). However, I could not find any sufficient "how to" article. Plus, I have no possibility to use enterprise products (Terracotta BigMemory etc.).

```
public class Customer{
    private Integer id;
    private String name;

    public Customer(){}

    //setters getters
}
```

Feel free to assume that elements are containing Customer information as above.
I only need to know how to connect to a remote server via    CacheManager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ehcache does not provide distribution for its open source implementation - its available in the paid product.  For distribution, you can look at hazelcast or infinispan.